# Can you change HTML source code when you click HTML button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arduino

Is it possible that when I click a HTML button, the source code changes?

For example if there's a line on HTML that says

```
  <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
```

Is it possible to change it so it says

```
  <p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">1</span> times.</p>
```

when I read the source code or Page source?

I am using the Arduino to send a HTTP request that would get the HTML code of the page. As a result, the Arduino is essentially getting what we see when we look at the page source. Is that different from when you "inspect an element"?

Comment: have u tried anything yet ??

Comment: yes, when you change html value using $('#displayCount').html('1') it will actually change in the html source.

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/HLypn/2/

Comment: "Source code" or "page source" options typically refer to the unmodified content that was received from the server. You can alter the live Element created from the markup and "*Inspect*" it in the developer tools most browsers have. But, you can't make the browser pretend it downloaded the altered version.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").click(function(){
    $("#displayCount").html("1");
});
```

using jQuery with http://api.jquery.com/click/

Edit:

If you wanna do a dynamic increment, do it as provided by the others:

```
 $("input").click(function(){
    var oldcount = parseInt($("#displayCount").html());
    $("#displayCount").html(oldcount++);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please search before you ask a new question.

```
<button>click to up the count</button>
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
<script>
    $('button').click(function () {
        var newCount = parseInt($('#displayCount').text()) + 1;
        $('#displayCount').text(newCount);
    });
</script>
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe5e5/

Answer (score 0):

how about it?

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  $("#displayCount").html(parseInt($("#displayCount").text()) + 1);
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this code

```
<script>
var count = 0;
function increment_Count(){
    count +=1;
    document.getElementById('displayCount').innerHTML=count;
}
</script>
<p>The button was pressed <span id="displayCount">0</span> times.</p>
<input type="button" onclick="increment_Count();" value="Click To Increment"/>
```